# "x FOR y" in column definition of DB2 create table statement

Tags: sql, db2, create-table

This is the DB2 `create table` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_F.TABLE_A (
    LEAFDESCRIPTION FOR F7UY2 CHAR(10) CCSID 1141  NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT
    ...
```

What does `LEAFDESCRIPTION FOR F7UY2` mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

It allows you to specify the short name usable from (older) RPG programs on the i and some system utilities.  In this case, `LeafDescription` is the long name usable from SQL, and `F7UY2` usable inside RPG, etc (and SQL, but long names are usually preferred for obvious reasons).

---

[It's part of the system-specific behavior available on the i](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm).

See, the i (iSeries, Systemi, AS/400) started out as a *very* different machine.  Several decades ago, before SQL was really a thing.  And at the time, field and table names were limited to around 6 characters, and programs were written with this in mind.

Now, flash forward to when SQL comes around.  On the i, DB2 SQL got retrofitted (of a sort) on top of the existing file system.  This meant that, among other things, you could query over your existing files with SQL *without* recreating or repopulating them.
Unfortunately, it also meant they were stuck with the original, semi-cryptic names, in part because you still had all the original *programs* too.  If you created (or re-created, as the case may be) a table via SQL, RPG programs couldn't reference it.  So this allowed you to specify a name it *could* reference - which meant you could switch to SQL-based tables (which had some additional, new, advantages) without needing to change your programs.  Even with the name-length restriction being lifted in recent versions of RPG, the ability to avoid renaming everything all at once is a boon.

Comment: One other point, it's customary to assign a short name for new tables.  Even if you're using long names everywhere.  As otherwise the system assigns one.  `LEAFDESCRIPTION` would have a system generated short name of `LEAFD00001`.